# How does concatenation of an array work in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, plotly, ejs

So, I am trying to make a variable receive always a new value and the past values. Is there a way to do something like that with the object that mySQL has returned? Something like this: SQL - {10,11,20}

In a loop, the variable should keep the past value it received and add a new value.
for {
variable - 10 
variable - 10,11
variable - 10,11,20
}

And yes, I am a student and I found no viable way to do this. I've tried concatenation, but it doesn't work.

```
          <% for (var i = 0; i < barras.length; i++){ %>
          barras = <%= JSON.parse(barras[i].progresso)%> + "," + <%= 
JSON.parse(barras[i].progresso)%> ;     
              <%}%>
```

The view file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<% if(barras){ %>
  <ul>
    <% for (var i = 0; i < barras.length; i++) { %>
      <li>
        <%= JSON.parse(barras[i].progresso) %>
      </li>
    <%}%>
  </ul>
<% } %>
  <div id="myDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
  <script>
  <% if(barras){ %>
          <% for (var i = 0; i < barras.length; i++){ %>
              barras = <%= JSON.parse(barras[i].progresso)%> + "," + <%= JSON.parse(barras[i].progresso)%> ;     
          <%}%>
  <% } %>
    data = [{ 
      type: 'bar', 
      x: [barras],
      y: 'teste', 
      orientation: 'h' 
    }]; 

    console.log(barras);


Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the route for this view:

```
app.get('/barras', function(req,res){
    console.log('Database connection online');
    connection.query('select progresso,nome from barra', function(error,result){
        barras = result;
        console.log(barras);
        res.render('admin/barras',barras);
    });
});
```

Comment: Really not clear what you are trying to accomplish (or what you are asking). Unless you use `barras` inside the loop it will get overwritten every iteration and once loop completes will have the value of last iteration of loop

Comment: I am trying to use the value of barras (which is an integer) to plot out a graph using plotly.

Comment: And what does that have to do with the code shown?

Comment: The thing is, even if I put the code for the bar graph inside the for loop, it doesn't generate a line for every value selected from the SQL Column....

Comment: The code shown is currently the code that gets the sql response from the route and then stores the result in the variable "barras"

Comment: You probably need to pass an array to the chart...not a single string

Comment: data = [{ 
      type: 'bar', 
      x: [barras],
      y: 'test', 
      orientation: 'h' 
      }]; 

   

    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);

Comment: You need to clarify. This is extremely difficult to comprehend.

Comment: Exactly! But that is why I asked about concatenation. Isn't it a way to create an array with the response obtained every for loop?

Comment: Create an array outside the loop and push into that array every iteration

Comment: Would be a lot easier to help if you provided an example of expected results and sample of each sql row from query

Comment: How? I need the information to be obtained with every iteration of the loop. how would that look?

Comment: surely. one sec...

Comment: The SQL array returns this object: {10,11,20}

Comment: But using this code above, plotly only plots a single bar (20) instead of three separate graph bars

Comment: I put the rest of the codes on snippets in the question above

Comment: I thought about creating some sort of concatenation as to keep the past values in the variable, but I truly found no material regarding this issue... By the way. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating things a bit imo. It's simpler to create the values you want to iterate from the original array before performing the iteration.

For example, the array `[[10], [10, 11], [10, 11, 20]]` can be constructed from `[10, 11, 20]` like this:

```js
const a = [10, 11, 20];
const b = [];

a.forEach((n, i) => {
  b.push(a.slice(0, i).concat(n));
});

console.log(b);
```

And then just do whatever you want with it:

```
for (const values of b) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I truly don't get it. The array is variable because it is a result from a SQL query. That is why I am confused as to why and how this would work... If you don't mind me asking, how would that look, if we didn't declare the integers inside "a"

Comment: Would I just have to replace the numbers in a with the result from the route? Like: var a = <%= JSON.parse(barras[i].progresso)%> and then the code you've shown?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to be the result for e.g. `[10, 11, 20]`? I don't quite understand what you want to do.

Comment: The result is any variable that was previously stored in SQL. So basically, I have a route called "Save", where I input the data I want in a form and it gets stored in SQL. Then, the route '/barras' gets this information and passes it to a result called barras, so it can be used on the view, the EJS file. Since the code for the chart is on the ejs file, I am confused if this method can be used to capture whatever the amount of values is stored in SQL and then plotted out on the chart... Basically it needs to the same as the snippet you've sent!

Comment: Seems like you want the following: `<% if(barras){ const b = []; barras.forEach((n, i) => {
  b.push(barras.slice(0, i).concat(n)); barras = b; } %>` but it's still unclear to me tbh.

Comment: It doesn't work... But I truly appreciate the help! NODE.JS has returned an error...

Comment: @LeonardoMatiazzo Yeah, I had a syntax error in the code above. Try `<% if (barras) { const b = []; barras.forEach((n, i) => { b.push(barras.slice(0, i).concat(n)); }); barras = b; } %>`. I cannot really test the code, sorry.

Comment: I know. It is tough to try to iterate this array with this code

Comment: I'm having this headache for a few days now. But it is necessary to implement in the chart :(

Comment: And I still got a negative evaluation for this question! Hahah, oh well. Can't please everyone. Thanks nonetheless @FK82 :)

Comment: Sure! You should keep trying though. Doesn't seem like you're far off from a solution.